# Incoming call notification that supports landscape mode

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, calls, screen, car-dock

With my HTC One V in the car dock in landscape mode, incoming call notifications still appear in portrait mode. Is there a way I can configure or replace this with something that will display properly in landscape mode?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't something that can be done natively (as far as my research has turned up). The next best thing I found were car dock apps, like [Car Home Ultra](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=spinninghead.carhome&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsInNwaW5uaW5naGVhZC5jYXJob21lIl0), which force everything to rotate into landscape and/or display a driver-friendly UI. I'm not sure if it will work for all versions of Android and what other limitations there are but it's worth a try, I guess. If all else fails, try [Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fameit.rotate).